# Pass value scope to another

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

For now, i have a controller which allow to get data (json) from database, with a search input.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MailCtrl',function($scope,itemFactory){
    $scope.init = function(){
         $scope.items = {};
         var search = $('#input').val();
         mailFactory.getItems(search).success(function(data){
             $scope.items = data;
         });
    }
    $('#input').keyup(function(){
         $scope.init()
    });


});

app.factory('itemFactory', function($http){
    var factory = {};
    factory.getItems = function(search) {
        return $http.get("/admin/get_saved_items/?search="+search);
    }
return factory;
)};
```

This controller allows to populate a list with only the username (displayed). but data from database looks like

```
[{"username" : "username1","first_name":"first_name1","last_name":"last_name1"},
{"username" : "username2","first_name":"first_name2","last_name":"last_name2"},..]
```

What I would like to do is on click on one element of this list populate an other $scope to populate a table with (username, first_name,last_name).
Moreover, when the search input is cleared to search an other username. The table keeps data and it's possible to add more entries on the table

**More INFO**

My template looks like

```
 %div{:ng=>{:controller=>'MailCtrl'}}
      %div.col-lg-6
           %input.form-control#unsername{:name =>'unsername',:type=>'text', :value=>parameters['unsername'],:autocomplete => "off"}

      %div.col-lg-6
           %ul{:ng=>{:repeat=>"item in items"}}
                 %li
                     {{ item.username }}

 %div.form-group{:ng=>{:controller=>'userCtlr'}}
      %table.table.table-bordered#table_user
           %tr
                %th
                   Username
                %th
                   first name
                %th
                   last name
           %tr{:ng=>{:repeat=>"user in users"}}
                 %td
                   {{user.username}}
                 %td
                   {{user.first_name}}
                 %td
                   {{user.las_name}}
```

Comment: for communication between multiple controllers, use a service http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a shared service and inject it to any controllers:

```
    angular.module("yourAppName", []).factory("mySharedService", function(){

        var mySharedService = {};

        mySharedService.values = {};

        mySharedService.setValues = function(params){
            mySharedService.values = params;
        }

        return mySharedService; 
   });
```

And after inject it to controller. For example:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, mySharedService) {
  var obj = $scope.someObj; 
  mySharedService.setValues(obj);
}

function AdditionalCtrl($scope, mySharedService) {
  $scope.var2= myService.values;
}
```

**UPDATE:** for Stef comment.
If you want pass loaded data from one controller to another controller, you can call passing function in ng-click() and broadcasting needed event from sharedService.

**View:**

```
<input ng-model="someModel" ng-click="passData(items)">
```

**FirstController:**

```
 function FirstCtrl($scope, mySharedService) {
      $scope.passData(params){
         mySharedService.setValues(params);
      }
 }
```

**SharedService:**

```
    angular.module("yourAppName", []).factory("mySharedService", function($rootScope){

        var mySharedService = {};

        mySharedService.values = {};

        mySharedService.setValues = function(params){
            mySharedService.values = params;
            $rootScope.$broadcast('dataPassed');
        }

        return mySharedService; 
   });
```

**SecondController:**

```
 function SecondController($scope, mySharedService) {
    $scope.$on('dataPassed', function () {
        $scope.newItems = mySharedService.values;
    });
 }
```

Comment: I'm starting with angularjs. How can I call this by clicking on one list element? (ng-click??)

Comment: @Stefrob I update my answer for your specify question :)